# How to add a Google AdSense async script into my SSR remix run website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, remix.run, google-ads-script

After going through a lot of hurdles I managed to put on the ads.txt file, robots.txt and dynamic sitemap.xml to my site and they all work flawlessly.

A while back my website was approved by google AdSense for monetization, all I need to do was add a link tag and few scripts tags to my website head tag to get the ads showing. Adding links was very easy when using remix, the issue comes when I need to load external async scripts.

The script I need to add to my head is this:

```html
<script
  async
  src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

When I check in the console, I see that my script has been added but the JavaScript has not executed. I am sure there are no issues with my google account and everything is fine there. **It is just that ads are not showing in my website because the script is not loaded correctly.**

Sometimes when I clear the cache and reload the website again, the **ads appear only on the homepage for 1 second then disappear.**  This is the reason I think the script is not being loaded into my SSR app correctly.

I looked everywhere for the solution and even posted on remix github repo, no luck just yet.
Out of all the solutions I found, here is what I tried:

dangerouslySetInnerHTML: Did not work

adding the script after mount using the useEffect (I mount the async script as it is after the setIsMounted is true): Did not work

using defer instead of async: Did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing the script from the head tag. Then I created a component that checks to see if the script is currently in the document head on location changes.  If it is, then I push an ad. If not I add it first and then push an ad.

Here is some code.

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  handleAds();
}, [location.key]);

const handleAds = () => {
  // check if script exists yet
  if (!document.getElementById("adsbygoogleaftermount")) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.id = "adsbygoogleaftermount";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.src =
      "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
// push ad with every location change
window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || [];
window.adsbygoogle.push({});
};

return (
  <div className="mt-4">
    <div key={location.key}> // <-- this is important
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
        data-ad-format="auto"
        data-full-width-responsive="true"
      ></ins>
    </div>
 )
}
```

This worked for placed ads as well as auto ads.